# Liking my page on Facebook shows the wrong image

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I've just updated my site to include og: tags and add Facebook like buttons, twitter buttons, etc. However, when I click the Like button and then go look at my Facebook profile, the image used is wrong.

This is the page on my site I'm referring to: http://www.inadaydevelopment.com/app/android/10bii-financial-calculator

My `<head>` tag includes the following `og:image` tags:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.inadaydevelopment.com/sites/default/files/app-10biiFinancialCalculator-Android-1-AmortizationSchedule.png">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.inadaydevelopment.com/sites/default/files/app-10biiFinancialCalculator-Android-2-CashFlowDiagram-Landscape.png">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.inadaydevelopment.com/sites/default/files/app-10biiFinancialCalculator-Android-4-Equation.png">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.inadaydevelopment.com/sites/default/files/app-10biiFinancialCalculator-Android-6-UnevenCashflowsNPV.png">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.inadaydevelopment.com/sites/default/files/app-10biiFinancialCalculator-Icon.png">
```

However, the image being shown on my Facebook profile is the little twitter icon I have in the sidebar which links to my twitter account:

[image]

When I look at the Facebook Debugger for my url, it shows the images that I have listed above in the og:image tags:

[image]

Why is Facebook grabbing the twitter icon out of my sidebar instead of using the og:image tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have the og:image tags on the page when you first added the Like button to your page?

If not, then Facebook may have picked up the twitter image before you added the tags.  Facebook caches the information it gets for the page, so if would keep the Twitter image even after you have updated the og:image tags.
Facebook says that it will refresh the data every 24 hours, though my own experiences indicate that might not be the case for pages with low 'like' counts.

However, you can force Facebook to refresh it's data using the Debugger - as you have done that already, did you checked your 'like' box afterwards to see if the image changed?

For reference, I 'liked' you page and the image that shows it the first image in the list you have in the og:image tags.

Comment: Oh, well that's a relief! and you're absolutely right, I just checked my profile again and the image has been updated. Thanks!